# Удалить get параметр htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Необходимо убрать `?page=1` из запроса:

```
https://domain.com/sometext/sometext/?page=1
```

Мой вариант не работает:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?page=1$ https://domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Экранировал RewriteRule ^(.*)\?page=1$ https://domain.com/$1 [L] не помогло

Comment: Если честно забыл как. А в RewriteCond что?

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?page=1$ А RewriteCond вообще обязательно указывать?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=1$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]